# How can I make a cipher code in javascript using a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I need to use a for loop to add 2 random letters to the string inputed into the text box and returned in the encrypted string box when the button is clicked. So, for example, if cat was inputted it could return like cynarwtpp. I am new to for loops and unsure how to proceed from here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var uncoded_array = uncoded.split("");
var coded_str = "";
var alphabet = new  Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");













</script>

<form action="">
Enter a String: <input type="text" name="uncoded" ></br>
<input type="button" value="cipher" onClick=document.forms[0].coded.value=    ></br>
Encrypted String: <input type="text" name="coded" ></br>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function makecoded()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

this will work for you and will give you some random string then you can add it anywhere

Comment: Thank you, how would I implement this using the array I already have rather than var possible?